# Cell padding affected by contained ASP NET image

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have an ASP net image contained within an HTML table cell, but for some reason there seems to be extra padding at the bottom of the cell.

[image]

I have tried a number of things, with no luck:

- Removing CSS padding.
- Removing the right hand "Logged in" cell to check it isn't influencing it the other cell.
- Adjusting the size of the source image. The padding stays 3px high.

  ```
          <td style="width:200px; vertical-align:top;">
          <table class="customTable" style="width:100%; table-layout: fixed">
              <tr style=" padding:0px;">
                  <td style="width:48px; padding:0px;">
                      <asp:Image ID="imgUser" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Media/user_anon.png" CssClass="userImage" />
                  </td>
                  <td class="customCell">
                      <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Text="Label">Logged in</asp:Label>
                      <asp:Image ID="image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Media/dropdown.png" />
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
  ```

CSS:

```
.customTable {
font-size:smaller;
text-align:center;
border-collapse: collapse; 
}

.userImage {
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: if it is live can you post the link? it is easy to debug there.

Comment: add a `margin: 0;` to img, probably will solve your issue `img {margin:0;}`

Comment: I would really discourage the use of tables, but with that said, it's probably the <td> that has a padding or the image that has a margin.

Comment: @jiff I added the recommended margin tweak to the CssImage field (Updated in question), but to no avail.

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann I've set the <td> padding and Image margin to 0px in my updated question. No luck I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you checked that your image doesn't have any whitespace? that it's trimmed

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann Yup it's a solid 48 x 48 image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think found your problem and made two fiddle for test, look first example:

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7tLg5ns/)**

It's exactly like your problem, right?

**now look this one:**

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7tLg5ns/1/)**

You need to set `display: block` for `img`

```
#imgUser {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Superb. Much appreciated, jiff!